# linq to specific part of xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am working with an XML document and extracting specific parts of it to create a new object. I have dealt with navigating to the doc-number and date (appNumber & appDate properties respectively). However I have not been able to navigate to the applicant's name.

By looking at the local variables at runtime, I can see that I have managed to navigate to the right element, however I can't seem to get the name value from this.

[image]

[image]

```
var myCase = from theCases in allCasesXML.Descendants("exchange-document")
             select new case_
             {
                 appNumber = (string)theCases.Element("bibliographic-data").Element("application-reference").Element("document-id").Element("doc-number"),
                 appDate = (from p in theCases.Descendants("application-reference").Descendants("document-id")
                            where ((string)p.Attribute("document-id-type") == "epodoc") && (p.Element("date") != null)
                            select (p.Element("date").Value)).FirstOrDefault(),
                 applicant = (string)(from q in theCases.Descendants("applicants").Descendants("applicant")//.Descendants("applicant-name")
                              where ((string)q.Attribute("data-format") == "original") && (q.Element("name") != null)
                              select (q.Descendants("name")).FirstOrDefault().Value.FirstOrDefault())
                 //                          title = "",
                 //                          pubNumber = "",
                 //                          pubDate = ""
             };
```

Comment: Why don't you just de-serialize it to an object? You can use VS 'Paste special' feature to get a class representation of your XML structure that's ready for de-serialization. You avoid that horrendous LINQ to XML query and get to work with a strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provided the answer:

```
      applicant = (from q in theCases.Descendants("applicants").Descendants("applicant")//.Descendants("applicant-name")
      where ((string)q.Attribute("data-format") == "original")// && (q.Element("name") != null)
      select q.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```